# If Then Else in Infopath (Xpath): how to ?

Tags: sharepoint

I've a module in InfoPath / Sharepoint, a query field, and some fields.
I want to perform in formula a simple :

```
If (Condition) then
   True Condition
Else 
   False Condition
```

In particular I want to write this formula:

If (FieldA = "") then
   Get FieldB
else 
   Get FieldA

How to do in InfoPath formula ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use this as a default value, you can simply use the `conditional default values`. Therefor just use the following snippet:

```
(TrueResult | ElseResult) [(BoolCondition) + 1]
```

And in your case:

```
(FieldA | FieldB) [(string-length(FieldA) > 0) + 1]
```

For more information on this see:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/infopath/2006/11/27/conditional-default-values/